# Is there a good solution to a composite pattern, where a root element is needed, but no element can be root?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a structure where, executing Update(); on the root element will recursively traverse the structure and execute Update(); on all child nodes.

This works just like I want it to, however, no element seem to qualify as being the root element. It looks like this

[image: A simplified version of the data structure]

This is what I ended up doing. I created a class called GameHandlerRoot, which does nothing, except act like a root. Call Update(); on this, and everything updates. Is this viable? There must be better solutions than a fake.

To be specific, even if you could find an element that would qualify as a root, I am only interested in a solution, where no such element exists.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have your solution. It is adequate and appropriate for the task at hand. You didn't have a clear root element. You needed one. You added it. Done.

The other obvious design is not not embed a root for the sole purpose of having a home for an omnibus update, but a simple structure (list, say) of items that are updatable. E.g. `updatable = [CharacterHandler, ItemHandler]`. Then iterate over this list, say in a `globalUpdate()` function. This has the virtue of not trying to overlay the aggregation of updatable elements onto the OOP structure / class hierarchy. In the "old days," kicking everything into a class-based Model-View-Controller-etc hierarchy was considered virtuous. But over time delegation- and aggregation-based approaches have gained more currency, as the weaknesses of all-classes-all-the-time designs became more apparent.

But separating out just the update operation into a non-class structure has inelegances of its own. Six one way, half a dozen the other. The root class you've added seems fine.

FYI, this type of design strategy question is often better posed to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Stack Overflow is more for "it doesn't work!" issues, where programmers is more about stylistic and strategy choices.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that solution could work as well. The composite structure allows execution of Node (n) and downwards, which I think I prefer. I will jump over to programmers right away, sounds like something I'd like. :)